# How to maintain a YouTube Playlist when entries become unavailable

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

I have several playlists that I have made on YouTube to keep track of my favourite videos and share the playlists with other people. However, over time, some videos get removed by their owners, some are restricted and made private or not available to playlists. So I need to perform maintenance on the playlists such as find alternative source of the same or similar content to replace the broken item in the list.

Is there a way for me to maintain my lists and prevent them becoming stale lists of out of date or broken links?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your playlist of YouTube videos in [mixpod](http://www.mixpod.com) or [playlist.com](http://www.playlist.com) and it will at least show you which videos are lost.

Caveats:

1. This works only for videos whose content owner allows embedding.
2. I'm not aware of an option to import playlists from Youtube on either site so you need to add the links manually.
3. playlist.com is not availabe in certain countries

Answer (score 0):

I know of [Youlister](http://youlister.duckdns.org), unlike others it also offers the option to mass delete playlists.

But unfortunately nothing to verify entries/URL's.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way for me to maintain my lists and prevent them becoming stale lists of out of date or broken links?

The safest way is to use a [program that can download YouTube playlists](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/11637/903), and keep a backup on your disk.

Answer (score -1):

I guess it's not exactly the tool you're searching but it may be of some use : if you keep your playlists in a text file, **[roll.io](http://roll.io/)** search for videos corresponding to each line.

Comment: No good. This isn't a local playlist. It's a youtube playlist on youtube.com.